# How do I make Apache serve a single static page no matter what the entered URL is?

Tags: apache2, dns

I'm making an advertisement blocking DNS server that redirects all the advertisement domains to an instance of [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server). So something like

```
www.addomain.com
```

gets redirected to

```
dnsserver.localnetwork
```

However, occasionally I come across links more like

```
www.addomain.com/some_ad
```

which gets redirected to

```
dnsserver.localnetwork/some_ad
```

which doesn't even exist and hence raises a `404` error.

I was hoping that there would be some way to make Apache serve `index.html`, regardless of the actual request. Otherwise, if you have an alternate solution that does not involve Apache, I'm up for that too.

Comment: You could have a look at apaches mod_rewrite. Redirecting everything from after the domain to /index.html

Comment: This seems like an inefficient way of doing adblocking.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen How would you do it? Most adblockers work on a similar concept. Block or redirect the requests to the advertising domains. I'll be glad to implement a better alternative if you have one.

Comment: To be honest, I use noscript and the default adblock plugins. If that is not sufficient, then you can either use a hosts file (takes work to maintain) or a proxy (privoxy), but again it takes more work to maintain a blacklist yourself. See https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/ and https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/ , you may need alternates depending on your browser.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Ubuntu, make sure [`mod_alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) is enabled:

```
sudo a2enmod alias
```

Then in your VirtualHost directive you can use [`AliasMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#aliasmatch).

Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /path/to/your/host
    ServerName yourdomain.com
    DirectoryIndex index.html

    AliasMatch ^/(.*)$ /path/to/your/host/index.html

    <Directory "/path/to/your/host">
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now everything gets redirected to `/index.html`.

Comment: My JS, CSS, and images are getting redirected as well with this solution.  Is there any way to prevent this without doing a big regex that checks the extension of the request?

Comment: You could always structure your project so that JS/CSS and images are in separate folders from your index.html and then route different URLs to them, e.g. coming from django, throw them all in a folder called `static`, your index.html in a folder called `templates`, then route all URLs with a <YOUR_HOST>/static/... to the static folder and everything else to the index.html in the template folder.

Answer (score 8):

You need a rewrite rule in your .htaccess file.  Something like the following should work:

```
RewriteRule ^*$  http://www.addomain.com/index.html [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: That does a redirect. It doesn't directly serve index.html.

Answer (score 1):

Another more simple option would be to change the 404 error page to the static page that you want to show for all pages on your site. So, look for this line (or something similar) in your apache2 configuration files:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/not_found.html
```

And change the "/errors/not_found.html" to: "/index.html"